# Using npm curlrequest and sometimes get message ERROR: Partial file. Only a part of the file was transferred

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl

Any idea how I can resolve the message below? It only happens sometimes.

I am doing a curl request against a remote server to get some JSON back...

I will get this :

```
ERROR:  Partial file. Only a part of the file was transferred.
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by changing the endpoint API url host. The server that I must have been connecting too was having slow performance causing the data to take long to get returned on curl response.